# ValidationSummary doesn't show Errors

Tags: asp.net, validationsummary

I have a problem with my gridview which won't show the ValidationSummary-errors anymore. The Headertext of the ValidationSummary does show up as well as the * which I set to appear whenever the ExpressionValidation fires.

I'm quite sure it worked before, but I don't know why it doesn't anymore. At first I thought it might have something to do with the other GridViews on the page as I have like 5 different GridView in different TabPanels, but I already made one validationgroup per GridView.

Markup:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
    <ContentTemplate>
       <asp:GridView ID="gvBBG" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="ID" SkinID="gvWithoutWidth">
         <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/GridView/gv_edit.png" CommandName="Edit"/>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                   <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/GridView/gv_cancel.png" CommandName="Cancel" CausesValidation="false"/>
                   <asp:ImageButton Id="ibUpdate" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/GridView/gv_update.png" CommandName="Update"  CausesValidation="true"
                        ValidationGroup="UpdateBBG" Enabled="true" OnClientClick="return confirm('Datensatz einspielen/aktualisieren?')"/>
                </EditItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>
           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="KV West" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
               <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="tbKVWest" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("KVWestFormatted") %>' ValidationGroup="UpdateBBG" Width="50px" Height="15px"></asp:TextBox>
                     <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvKVWest" ValidationGroup="UpdateBBG" runat="server"
                           ControlToValidate="tbKVWest" ErrorMessage="Bitte KVWest als Summe angeben"
                           SetFocusOnError="true">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator> 
                      <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revKVWest" ValidationGroup="UpdateBBG" runat="server"
                           ValidationExpression="^[0-9]{1,9}((\,)[0-9]{1,2})?$" ControlToValidate="tbKVWest" SetFocusOnError="true">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
              </EditItemTemplate>
              <ItemTemplate>
                  <%# Eval("KVWestFormatted")%>
              </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
....
      </Columns>
          <EmptyDataTemplate>Keine Daten vorhanden</EmptyDataTemplate>
  </asp:GridView>
      <p>
            <asp:ValidationSummary ID="vsUpdate3" runat="server" ShowMessageBox="true" ShowSummary="true" ValidationGroup="UpdateBBG" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="Red" 
                 EnableClientScript="true" Enabled="true" HeaderText="Validierung..." />
      </p>
```

Would be nice if you guys could help me out here. Im not quite sure what the problem is .. maybe it's the UpdatePanel? Maybe I made some dumb mistake ..? I'm rather clueless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found The problem .. I have to set the errormessage for both RequiredFieldValidator and RegularExpressionValidator. ;) You don't need the validationgroup inside of the textbox btw.

Answer (score 1):

You button validation group is update but all other have validation group updatebbg so change validation group of ur button to updatebbg

Comment: Ugh .. I'm blind. Thank you :)

Comment: u have to specify the txt box validation group too my freind
like
<asp:TextBox ID="tbKVWest" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("KVWestFormatted") %>' Width="50px" Height="15px" ValidationGroup="UpdateBBG"></asp:TextBox>

Comment: Still nothing .. updated my original post. I'm starting to get pissed. Thanks for your help anyways. :/

Comment: if it show error for required field than problem is in ur RegularExpressionValidator might it doesnt give error..so pls check it ...confirm it that it gives erro when u input wrong format.....

Comment: Yea .. you're probably right. Crap .. now I have to set the validationexpression again. I had a good website explaining how to, but I can't seem to find it. -.-

Comment: friend watch carefully......i m sure u will find....it best of luck ....hope my comment answer helped u bit ....sorry for not solving ur problem fully,,,,,,,but i belive that validation summary is worknig well ....

Comment: it can't be the expression .. I changed it up so that it won't accept strings .. which it didn't before, too. Well .. I think I'm about to find out what the real problem is. Thanks for your help

Comment: pls tell me too what is the actual problem so i also get know a new thing........wish u luck ........